# How can I use Buckets with AEM QueryBuilder

Tags: aem

I've implemented a custom `PredicateEvaluator` to create facets with buckets, based on examples like [this one](https://github.com/Adobe-Consulting-Services/acs-aem-samples/tree/master/bundle/src/main/java/com/adobe/acs/samples/querybuilder/facets/impl)

It seems to be working. I can see the count in my buckets changing depending on the criteria.

But what comes next? The query returns a `SearchResult`, which has a `Hit` collection and a `Facet` collection (which in turn has a `Bucket` collection), but I don't see a way to combine these sets - I can't find a `Hit.getBuckets()` or a `Buckets.getHits()` method. I assumed that I'd be able to use buckets to categorize my search results, but I don't see any way to associate a `Hit` with a `Bucket`. How do I figure out which hits fall in which buckets, or is this just not their purpose?

Answer (score 0):

A `Bucket` can be used to refine a `Query`.

```
    SearchResult unrefinedResult = query.getResults();
// get a bucket from the unrefined result - in real code you'd iterate.
    Bucket bucket = unrefinedResult .getFacets().get("my_facet").getBuckets().get(0);
    SearchResult refinedResult = query.refine(bucket).getResults();
```

This approach requires you to execute another search, which is possibly more overhead than you want to incur.